# Date conversion using POSIXct stores as list as numbers rather than date format

Tags: r, posixct, strptime

I am working on a code to convert a column of dates which are not in date format.  After uploading the file into R some of the date's are changed into numeric numbers and rest of the dates are in character.

1st Set - Some dates are uploaded as = "43984.609722222223" "43986.468055555553" "43986.468055555553"

2nd Set - Some are in date but in character = "6/21/20 09:53:00" "6/21/20 16:09:29" "6/22/20 08:47:41"

I have used the code below to change the 1st set to numeric.

```
n_row <- nrow(data_time)
for(i in 1:n_row)
{
  data_time$vald[i] <- as.numeric(as.character(data_time[i,1]))
}
```

for 2nd set -

```
for(j in 1:n_row)
    {
          if(!is.na(data_time$vald[j])) 
              {
                data_time$vald1[j]<- as.POSIXct(data_time$vald[j]*(60*60*24),origin="1899-12-30",tz="Asia/kolkata")
              }
            else if(is.na(data_time$vald[j]))
               {
                 #data_time$vald1[j] <- "Yes"
                 data_time$vald1[j] <- strptime(data_time$Reported_Date[j],"%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S",tz="Asia/kolkata")


               }
       }
```

The conversion happens but not in the desired format.

```
data_time$vald1[j]<- as.POSIXct(data_time$vald[j]*(60*60*24),origin="1899-12-30",tz="Asia/kolkata")
```

The above code converts the numeric to dates but when storing in the table it is stored as "1591108680","1591269240".

For the dates in characters I used the below code

```
data_time$vald1[j] <- strptime(data_time$Reported_Date[j],"%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S",tz="Asia/kolkata")
```

the above code gives the right answer in the R console but while storing in the data frame it stores as numbers "1", 23", "34" as such.

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: Check out `anytime` package, it has very nice conversions with minimum work. Especially `anytime::anytime` function. Maybe you will have to specify origin or convert dates to numeric but this should be it.